# How to return and have a passby reference in the same function in C

Tags: c, return-value, pass-by-reference

I am looking to optimize the functions below . I have two use cases

1. I use the written value to print on to output console
2. I have to fill up a buffer which will sent over CAN

How do I effectively merge these functions into 1

```
    static float runningrate ;
    void get_rate_CAN(uint16_t* rate) {
        *rate = (uint16_t)truncf(runningrate);
        }
    
    
    uint16_t Getrate(void)
        {
        return (uint16_t)truncf(runningrate);                 
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need/benefit-from both? Either one can be used to simulate the other; you could change calls to `get_rate_CAN(&someui16);` to be `someui16 = Getrate();` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the first example for both:

```c
static float runningrate ; //you may want to assign a value here?
void get_rate(uint16_t* rate) {
    *rate = (uint16_t)truncf(runningrate);
}
```

Examples:

```c
uint16_t *buf = ...;
get_rate(buf);


// equivalent to `uint16_t output = Getrate();` from your original answer:
uint16_t output;
get_rate(&output);
printf("%u", output);
```

The & operator gets the address of the specified value so that it can be used as a reference.